# How to mock same class method in asp.net unit test

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

```cs
public class Controller
{

 public GetSomeData()
  {
    retun someData;
  }

 public dosomthing(Some someObj)
  {
    var getData = GetSomeData();
    return service.DosomethingElse(getData);
  }

}
```

I have mocked `service.DosomethingElse(getData);`.

I've also mocked `GetSomeData();` but it returns `""` (blank value) I want to return with `"myData"`.

I've written a `TestMethod` like this:

```cs
string someData ="myData";
var mockData = new Mock<Controller>();     
mockData.Setup(x => x.GetSomeData()).Returns(someData);

var mockDa = new Mock<Service>();         
mockDa.Setup(x => x.DosomethingElse(getData)).Returns(response);

Controller cObj= new Controller(mockDa.Object);

var actual = cObj.dosomthing(Some someObj);

Assert.AreEqual("expected",actual);
```

Please suggest how to mock `GetSomeData()` method of the same class.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. You can't mock the `GetSomeData` for the controller you are testing. You can only mock the dependencies you inject to the class.

Think about it this way:

1. A mock is an object with specific behavior, mocking a real class object
2. A class object has the proper behavior

You can't have a hybrid object, a little bit of mock and a little bit of class.

By the way, even if you could, you shouldn't. When you are testing a method, you also test the other methods of the same class that are used within. This is also the way you are testing the private functions of a class.